# Payfort: Invalid extra parameters "card_security_code"

Tags: payfort

Getting response code 00027 from payfort using Merchant page 2.0. This is happening when the card details are saved on the frontend.

{

```
  "amount": "9900",
  "response_code": "00027",
  "signature": "",
  "merchant_identifier": "",
  "access_code": "",
  "customer_ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "language": "en",
  "command": "PURCHASE",
  "merchant_extra": "3",
  "response_message": "Invalid extra parameters : card_security_code",
  "merchant_reference": "",
  "customer_email": "sufyan.khot@domain.com",
  "merchant_extra1": "domain.com/en",
  "merchant_extra2": "domain.com",
  "currency": "AED",
  "customer_name": "test test",
  "status": "00"
}
```